# Why Does My Asynchronous Code Run Synchronously When Debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to implement a method called `ReadAllLinesAsync` using the async feature. I have produced the following code:

```
private static async Task<IEnumerable<string>> FileReadAllLinesAsync(string path)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        while ((await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
        {

        }
    }
    return null;
}

private static void Main()
{
    Button buttonLoad = new Button { Text = "Load File" };
    buttonLoad.Click += async delegate
    {
        await FileReadAllLinesAsync("test.txt"); //100mb file!
        MessageBox.Show("Complete!");
    };

    Form mainForm = new Form();
    mainForm.Controls.Add(buttonLoad);
    Application.Run(mainForm);
}
```

I expect the listed code to run asynchronously and as a matter of fact, it does! But only when I run the code **without** the Visual Studio Debugger.

When I run the code **with** the Visual Studio Debugger attached, the code runs synchronously, blocking the main thread causing the UI to hang.

I have attempted and succeeded to reproduce the problem on three machines. Each test was conducted on a 64bit machine (either Windows 8 or Windows 7) using Visual Studio 2012.

I would like to know why this problem is occuring and how to solve it (as running without the debugger will likely hinder development).

Comment: `async`/`await` is not a guarantee that code will run asynchronously. If you really need that, you need to be more explicit about it, use `Task.Run` for instance.

Comment: I'm not sure why this behaves differently in the debugger, but your code sample is not truly asynchronous - it's just fake-asynchronous. A truly asynchronous solution would have to explicitly open the file for asynchronous access (the `StreamReader(string)` constructor does not do this).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm seeing the same problem as you to an extent - but only to an extent. For me, the UI is very jerky in the debugger, and *occasionally* jerky not in the debugger. (My file consists of lots of lines of 10 characters, by the way - the shape of the data *will* change behaviour here.) Often in the debugger it's good to start with, then bad for a long time, then it sometimes recovers.

I **suspect** the problem may simply be that your disk is too fast and your lines are too short. I know that sounds crazy, so let me explain...

When you use an `await` expression, that will *only* go through the "attach a continuation" path if it needs to. If the results are present already, the code just extracts the value and continues in the same thread.

That means, if `ReadLineAsync` always returns a task which is completed by the time it returns, you'll effectively see synchronous behaviour. It's entirely possible that `ReadLineAsync` looks at what data it's already got buffered, and tries to synchronously find a line within it to start with. The operating system may well then read more data from the disk so that it's ready for your application to use... which means that the UI thread never gets a chance to pump its normal messages, so the UI freezes.

I had *expected* that running the same code over a network would "fix" the problem, but it didn't seem to. (It changes exactly how the jerkiness is shown, mind you.) However, using:

```
await Task.Delay(1);
```

*Does* unfreeze the UI. (`Task.Yield` doesn't though, which again confuses me a lot. I suspect that may be a matter of prioritization between the continuation and other UI events.)

Now as for why you're only seeing this in the debugger - that still confuses me. Perhaps it's something to do with how interrupts are processed in the debugger, changing the timing subtly.

These are only guesses, but they're at least *somewhat* educated ones.

EDIT: Okay, I've worked out a way to indicate that it's at least *partly* to do with that. Change your method like this:

```
private static async Task<IEnumerable<string>>
    FileReadAllLinesAsync(string path, Label label)
{
    int completeCount = 0;
    int incompleteCount = 0;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var task = reader.ReadLineAsync();
            if (task.IsCompleted)
            {
                completeCount++;
            }
            else
            {
                incompleteCount++;
            }
            if (await task == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            label.Text = string.Format("{0} / {1}",
                                       completeCount,
                                       incompleteCount);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

... and create and add a suitable label to the UI. On my machine, both in debug and non-debug, I see *far* more "complete" hits than "incomplete" - oddly enough, the ratio of complete to incomplete is 84:1 consistently, both under the debugger and not. So it's only after reading about one in 85 lines that the UI *can* get a chance to update. You should try the same on your machine.

As another test, I added a counter incrementing in the `label.Paint` event - in the debugger it only executed 1/10th as many times as not in the debugger, for the same number of lines.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, the `async/await` pattern is truly asynchronous *on demand*, from the perspective of the load of the PC it's running on. This is presumably more efficient when it comes to threading but also somewhat presumptuous on its part because it assumes it can decide when I want it to run on the main thread. Is that right?

Comment: @TheSolution: I'm not sure what you mean by "truly asynchronous on demand". Basically an asynchronous method will return before truly completing if it has an `await` expression where the awaiter's `IsCompleted` property returns `false`. Does that translate to what you're talking about?

Comment: Let me ask it this way. Does it spin up another thread regardless, but that thread gets joined to the main thread so quickly that it appears it's synchronous?

Comment: @TheSolution: No, definitely not. `async` doesn't create any threads in itself, although some method calls may do so.

Comment: Just so I can get a really good understanding, [the doc states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) `... can't continue until the awaited asynchronous operation is complete. In the meantime, the method is suspended, and control returns to the method's caller.` Who creates the extra thread so control can be returned to the caller?

Comment: @TheSolution: There's no extra thread. The method just returns, having added a continuation to the awaitable operation. It's up to the operation to schedule the continuation appropriately when the operation has completed.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Thanks man, I'm sorry if I've been a burden my friend!

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that you are calling `await reader.ReadLineAsync()` in a tight loop that does nothing - except return execution to the UI thread after each await before starting all over again. Your UI thread is free to process windows events ONLY while `ReadLineAsync()` tries to read a line.

To fix this, you can change the call to `await reader.ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)`.

`await` waits for the completion of an asynchronous call and returns execution to the Syncrhonization context that called `await` in the first place. In a desktop application, this is the UI thread. This is a good thing because it allows you to update the UI directly but can cause blocking if you process the results of the asynchronous call right after the `await`.

You can change this behavior by specifying `ConfigureAwait(false)` in which case execution continues in a different thread, not the original Synchronization context.

Your original code would block even if it wasn't just a tight loop, as any code in the loop that processed the data would still execute in the UI thread. To process the data asynchronously without adding `ConfigureAwait`, you should process the data in a taks created using eg. Task.Factory.StartNew and await that task.

The following code will not block because processing is done in a different thread, allowing the UI thread to process events:

```
while ((line= await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(ln =>
    {
        var lower = (ln as string).ToLowerInvariant();
        Console.WriteLine(lower);
     },line);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is very informative and helpful. But do you have any idea why my code runs asynchronously when run *with* the debugger?

Comment: It's important to note that using `ConfigureAwait(false)` would prevent the method from *also* modifying the UI.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio isn't actually executing the asynchronous callback synchronously. However, your code is structured in such a manner that it is "flooding" the UI thread with messages that you may not need to execute on a UI thread. Specifically, when `FileReadAllLinesAsync` resumes execution in the body of the `while` loop, it does so on the `SynchronizationContext` that was captured on the `await` line in the same method. What this means is for every line in your file, a message is posted back to the UI thread to execute 1 copy of the body of that while loop.

You can resolve this issue by using `ConfigureAwait(false)` carefully.

1. In `FileReadAllLinesAsync`, the body of the while loop is not sensitive to which thread it runs on, so you can use the following instead:

   ```
   while ((await reader.ReadLineAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)) != null)
   ```
2. In `Main`, suppose you *do* want the `MessageBox.Show` line to execute on the UI thread (perhaps you also have a `buttonLoad.Enabled = true` statement there). You can (and will!) still get this behavior without any changes to `Main`, since you did not use `ConfigureAwait(false)` there.

I suspect the delays you observe in the debugger are due to .NET's slower performance in managed/unmanaged code while a debugger is attached, so dispatching each of those millions of messages to the UI thread is up to 100x slower when you have the debugger attached. Rather than try to speed up that dispatching by disabling features, I suspect item #1 above will resolve the bulk of your problems immediately.

Answer (score 1):

From [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=19957) in Microsoft Download Center :

> For performance reasons, if a task has already completed by the time
>   the task is awaited, control will not be yielded, and the function
>   will instead continue executing.

And

> In some cases, the amount of work required to complete the operation
>   is less than the amount of work it would take to launch the operation
>   asynchronously (e.g. reading from a stream where the read can be
>   satisfied by data already buffered in memory).  In such cases, the
>   operation may complete synchronously, returning a Task that has
>   already been completed.

So my last answer was incorrect (short-timing asynchronous operation ***is*** synchronous for performance reasons).

Comment: No, the code *isn't* always asynchronous. If the line is already available when `ReadLineAsync` is called, the thread will just keep going. Indeed, if *all* the lines are available without further blocking, the whole loop will execute within the `Click` handler.

Comment: I didn't say anything about being magical - I said it wasn't always asynchronous. If `ReadLineAsync` returns a completed task, the code will continue in the same thread just as if the call had been a blocking one to start with. How does that gel with your claim that it's "always asynchronous"? Perhaps you just need to edit the answer to explain what you mean by "always asynchronous" here.